# Confused with pe:documentViewer rendering pdf file in web app

Tags: pdf, primefaces-extensions

I have a web app that uses primefaces extensions. 
If I use

```
<pe:documentViewer id="verPdf" 
               height="500" 
               name="/resources/pdf/#{utentesBean.nomeFile}" />
```

it does not render PDF in view.

if I use

```
<pe:documentViewer id="verPdf" 
               height="500" 
               name="/resources/pdf/441.pdf" />
```

it shows the PDF .

Can anyone give an idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: My idea: check for errors... Client side AND server side

Comment: Thank you. There are no erros (visible). if i print the value of utentesBean.nomeFile it has the string value of 441.pdf.

Comment: And what is the difference in the client-side html then? Sure there are no network 404 errors or something?

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the developers of the document viewer component and I just tested it and it worked fine with both of the following:

```
<pe:documentViewer url="/sections/documentviewer/#{controller.bookFile}"/>

<pe:documentViewer library="books" name="#{controller.hoodFile}"/>
```

One thing I noticed above in your example is you were not using URL you were using "name" attribute and name is meant to be used with "library" as in my example above as a relative path to a resource folder called "books".

I think you want to change your code to...

```
<pe:documentViewer id="verPdf" 
               height="500" 
               library="pdf"
               name="#{utentesBean.nomeFile}" />
```